# sending sms messages from twilio trial number

Tags: asp.net, twilio

i have verified my own mobile number with twilio but the number is from a service provider in malaysia. i did the codes to send the sms but i am unable to receive it on my number. do i need a us or canada number or do i have to purchase a number from twilio in order to test the codes. below are the codes:

**WebForm1.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h4>To Number: </h4>
        <asp:TextBox ID="ToNumber" TextMode="password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <h4>SMS Message</h4>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Message" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <asp:Button ID="SendMessage" OnClick="SendMessage_OnClick" runat="server" Text="Send Message" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**WebForm1.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using Twilio;
namespace WebApplication4
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)


   {

    }

    protected void SendMessage_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string ACCOUNT_SID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ACCOUNT_SID"];
        string AUTH_TOKEN = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AUTH_TOKEN"];

        TwilioRestClient client= new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, ACCOUNT_SID);
        client.SendSmsMessage("(862) 373-1913", ToNumber.Text, Message.Text);

}
}
```

}

i have checked with visual studio 2012 that the codes are working but still can't seem to receive the sms. what should i do?

Comment: SendSmsMessage returns an object that contains a lot of status and possible error information. Please check the RestException member for information on what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

some numbers are not supported by twilio like start with 94,87.
By the it's work with vodafone company numbers.
Please try it.

Comment: i tried using a few numbers from twilio such as;
(971) 340-****
(862) 373-****
(971) 340-****
a few of the validated number are from the local telcos like digi(016) and maxis(012) but still to no avail.

Comment: P.S: im from malaysia and using malaysian telco services

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
var result = client.SendSmsMessage("(862) 373-1913", ToNumber.Text, Message.Text);
```

and take a look at `result`. If most of the fields are null, look at `result.RestException`. A common issue is with authentication.